# "status": 403, "error": "Forbidden" "message": "Access Denied" in postman spring boot code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm new in spring boot and trying to create authentication app, but after writing it i found an error in postman app :

> "timestamp": "2022-06-18T06:42:20.072+00:00",
> "status": 403,
> "error": "Forbidden"

This is my code :

i have 2 classes, one in Auth request and another is Auth response and I have a controller for both of them, this is the **AuthRequest  model**:

```
public class AuthRequest {
    @Email  @Length(max = 50 , min = 5)
    private String email;

    @Length(max = 50 , min = 2)
    private  String password;

    public AuthRequest(String email ,String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }
```

and this is my **Auth response model** :

```
public class AuthResponse {
    private String email ;
    private String accessToken;


    public AuthResponse(){}

    public AuthResponse(String email, String accessToken) {
        this.email = email;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }
```

This **Auth Request controller**:

```
    @RestController
    public class AuthController {
        @Autowired
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    
        @PostMapping("/login")
        public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody @Valid AuthRequest authRequest){
                try {
                    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authRequest.getEmail(),authRequest.getPassword()));
                    Employee employee = (Employee) authentication.getPrincipal();
                    String accessToken = "JWT access token here";
                    AuthResponse authResponse = new AuthResponse(employee.getEmail(), accessToken);
                    return  ResponseEntity.ok(authResponse);
                }catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
                        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).build();
                }
        }
    }


and this is my **config security class** :


@EnableWebSecurity
@CrossOrigin
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private IEmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(username -> employeeRepository.findByEmail(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User " + username + " not found. ")));
    }
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager AuthenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManager();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

}
```

and then, I post it to postman and this gave an error message and do not confirm :

[image]
Trace :
[image]
[image]
[image]
and i save it in the database :
[image]

Comment: Could you share stacktrace?

Comment: @Zixel can u check it pleaase ?

Comment: please dont post images of logs etc. its against the rules no one can read that stacktrace, edit your question and add the stacktrace properly formatted.

Comment: stack trace says `Employee.isDeleted`is set to null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `isDeleted` of the `Employee` object returned by the call to `employeeRepository.findByEmail(username)` is null and it's defined as not nullable (`boolean`).

Either return a not null value or change the property's type to `Boolean`.